# Why is the inclusion of the $ 0 $-vector part of the definition of a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am not seeing why a subspace must include $ 0 $. From what I am told, this inclusion means that the subspace is not “empty”, but I cannot see how the inclusion of $ 0 $ does this. For instance, can you not have a subspace of $ \Bbb{R}^{2} $ that is a line represented by $ y = x + 1 $, which will not intersect $ (0,0) $ of $ \Bbb{R}^{2} $ at all? This subspace appears to exists and to be an element of $ \Bbb{R}^{2} $ by addition and scalar multiplication, but unless I am mistaken, it does not satisfy this $ 0 $-vector inclusion requirement (unless this means it is NOT a subspace, but then that is not making sense).

Comment: Actually it satisfies none of those axioms. If you take $y,x$ such that $y = x + 1$ then $ay = ax + 1$ for a scalar $a$ if and only if $a = 1$ (the trivial case), and if you have $y = x + 1$, $z = w + 1$ then $y+z \neq (x + w) + 1$ in any situation.

Comment: @JHance, Isn't it that scalar multiplication by $a$ would be $ay=ax+a$?

Comment: You claimed that $x = y + 1$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. It is not. To be more precise, when we say "the line $y = x   + 1$" we mean the collection of all points $(x,y)$ such that $y  =x + 1$. So let $L$ be this set. To show it is closed under scalar multiplication means that $(x,y) \in L$ implies that $(ax,ay) \in L$ for every scalar $a$, that is to say $ax = ay  + 1$ for every scalar $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion seems to stem from thinking incorrectly that all linear things in $\mathbb R^2$ are vector subspaces. This is not the case, as is discussed in the remarks. One of the requirements of a vector space is that it is not empty, that with each vector there is its additive inverse, and that it is closed under vector addition. From this it follows that there is an $x$ in the subspace, and thus also $x-x$ is there, but thus $0$ is in the subspace.

Answer (score 0):

We want a subspace to be a vector space on its own.

Now, if a subspace $A$ of $V$ is to have an identity element for the addition, it has to be the element $0$ in $V$. That's why we must have $0\in A$ in order for $A$ to have an identity element for the addition and therefore be, possibly, a vector space on its own.

As for being non-empty, maybe you refer to a criterion to test if $A$ is a subspace of $V$ or not. If you know that $A$ is non-empty (but you don't necessarily know it contains $0$), then if it is closed under addition and under multiplication by a scalar it is a subspace.